# Understanding Serge Lang's Definition of Homotopy

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, homotopy-theory

I have been following Serge Lang's Complex Analysis text book and today I came across a chapter on homotopy. I have trouble visualising and honestly, understanding the definition that he has given in his book. Here is the definition from his book [image: Image 1]

Could somebody explain to me how I can visually interpret this? I would also be really grateful if someone had a graphic or visual that would illustrate what is meant in this definition. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The idea of homotopy is that you want to "continuously deform" one path into another. The [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) for homotopy has good explanations.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey thanks for the response. I already had a look prior to asking the question and what I couldn't understand is how does this definition effectively deform one path onto the other. With this question, I want to understand what idea is Lange trying to convey. Hope that makes sense, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Think of the 2 variables as "sliders" when you slide the first slider you move along a path determined by the second slider. When you move the second slider you change the path you are on. When you put the second slider at the start or end, the path given by the first slider is either $\gamma$ or $\eta$ respectively.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Homotopy_of_paths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $\psi(t,c)=\gamma(t)$. Since $\psi$ is continuous, if $c_1$ is slightly bigger than $c$, then $t\mapsto\psi(t,c_1)$ is a path which is close to $\gamma$. And if $c_2$ is slightly bigger than $c_1$, then $t\mapsto\psi(t,c_2)$ is a path which is close to the previous one. And so on, until you reach $d$. So, $\psi$ deforms $\gamma$ into $\eta$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have two questions which I will number because I think it will be easier to address them if you don't mind.

1) So basically one interval is for the paths (in this case [a,b]) and the other one ( [c,d] )is for this constant which acts basically as a distinguisher (or as a seperator) between the  members of the family of paths that start are defined on this interval? 

2) Also I wanted to ask you, do we just assume that both paths, delta and etta, have the same starting and ending points?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) I think that that's the usual option, yes, but Lang does not assume that.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In regards to 2), is this why he talks about parameterization; so that it would allow for curves of different starting points?

Comment: No. If $\gamma$ and $\eta$ have the same starting and ending points ($z$ and $w$ respectively), the definition is the same, except that we add that $\psi(a,u)$ is always equal to $z$ and that $\psi(b,u)$ is always equal to $w$.

Comment: Alright thanks. Just a quick question, how would you interpret visually what the function ψ is doing when the paths don't have the same starting and ending points?

Comment: I visualize it as a continuous familiy of curves, going from $\gamma$ to $\eta$.

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you for your help. My question has been answered to the fullest extent.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If two closed path are homotopic then  does they have same orientation? If not then how integral can be same always?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos   Please look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885015/question-about-independence-of-complex-contour-integral-over-homotopic-path)

Answer (score 3):

You can see each $f_x(t)=\psi(t,x)$ as a *continuous* family of paths, indexed by the points in the interval $[c,d]$.  The conditions mean that the initial path $f_c(t)$ is precisely $\gamma(t)$ and the final path is $\eta(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, for every $s\in[c,d]$, $\psi_s:[a,b]\to U,~\psi_s(t)=\psi(t,s)$ is a path with the property that $\psi_c=\gamma$ and $\psi_d=\eta$. So you could also view it as a continuous* function $[c,d]\to P(U)$, where I call $P(U)$ the set of all paths in $U$. Viewing it this way, it might be clearer what is meant by "continuous deformation": We take an interval $[c,d]$ and assign a path to each element of the interval in a way that if $s,s'\in[c,d]$ are close, then the paths $\psi_s$ and $\psi_{s'}$ are close, and the starting path is $\gamma$, while the end path is $\eta$.

[Here is a desmos example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q8kfe2ztbc) of a homotopy between a semicircle and a line, where you can play with a slider determining the parameter $s$. For $s=0$ you get the line as a path, and for $s=1$ you get the semicircle. $0<s<1$ gives semiellipses interpolating between the line and the circle.

* If we equip the set of paths with the right topology, but that's a technicality you don't need for the intuition behind the definition.