# Question About Independence Of Complex Contour Integral Over Homotopic Path.

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, contour-integration

From Complex analysis by Serge Lang.

> **Definition:** $C_1,C_2:[a,b]\mapsto U$ are two closed paths in open set $U\subset \mathbb C$.Then we say $C_1$ is homotopic to $C_2$ if there exist a continuous function $h: [a,b]\times [c,d]\mapsto U$ such that
>
> $$ h(t,c)=C_1(t) ~\text{and}  ~h(t,d)=C_2(t)$$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. And $h(a,s)=h(b,s)$ for $s\in [c,d]$.

Now there is  theorem in book

> Theorem 5.2: If $f$ is holomorphic function in $U\subset \mathbb C$ open. And $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two closed homotopic path in $U$ then $$\int_{C_1}~f=\int_{C_2}~f$$.

Consider

$C_1:[0,2\pi]\mapsto \mathbb C$ By $\theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$.
$C_2:[0,2\pi]\mapsto \mathbb C$ By $\theta \mapsto 2e^{i(2\pi-\theta)}$ then

$$\int_{C_1}~\frac1z~dz=2\pi i \ne -2\pi i=\int_{C_2}~\frac 1 z~dz$$.
Here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are homotopic in $\mathbb C \setminus {(0,0)}$. And $z\mapsto \frac 1 z$ is holomorphic in  $\mathbb C \setminus {(0,0)}$.
So we have all the hypothesis of theorem ,Then why both integral are not same ? Is homotopic path has same orientation
?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Those two paths are not homotopic, as shown by your example and the theorem. Alternatively, you can try to show that no function $h$ as in the definition exists for your $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  So "geometric intuition" about homotopic path namely **One can be continuously deformed into another** is not work "correctly" here. right?

Comment: Well I would say the intuition needs to be upgraded to include the "direction" of the path. You cannot continuously deform a closed circle that goes one way onto the closed circle that goes the other way, unless there is no hole inside the disk enclosed by the circle, in which case you can.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  Got it what you mean. Thank you .